# Unable to print document using SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sharpziplib

I am trying to print a ODT document using SharpZipLib. And I am getting the following error -

```
'LaserMaze.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: LaserMaze.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\lasermaze\LaserMaze\bin\Release\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

I have read that changing debug configurations usually helps in these cases. But so far I am unable to find a debug configuration where it works for me.

I am build using a Release configuration for Any CPU. 
And I have disabled "Just My Code" option also. 
But still no luck.

**Edit** - Here are more details for the problem -

```
public static void PrintScoreCard(Game currentGame) {
    string templateFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".odt"); ;
    File.WriteAllBytes((string)templateFilePath, Properties.Resources.ScoreCardTemplate);
    Odt odt = new Odt(templateFilePath);
    Odt.OdtDocFields inputs = odt.Inputs;
    string playerNames = "";
    foreach (string p in currentGame.team.players) {
        playerNames += "\r\n" + p;
    }
    foreach (string key in inputs.FieldNames)
    {
        //populate the inputs object.
    }
    odt.Print();
}
```

Code of Odt class can be found in the article - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24093/Printing-Documents-from-C-using-OpenOffice-Writer

Any leads?

Comment: "I am build using a `Release` configuration" - when you build release, you don't get debug symbols.  Are you trying to debug your code?  Also,  are you using a release version of SharpZipLib?  That wouldn't have debug symbols either.  The message you're getting is telling you that it will be really tough to debug any code in the referenced file.

Comment: @theGleep - I am OK with not getting debug messages. But even the prints are not coming. Why would that fail?

Comment: That's a whole different issue.  For *that* we'll probably want code examples, what  you've tried, what errors you're getting... all *kinds* of extra information.  At this point, your question is *kind of* like asking "I got up this morning, why does my coffee taste bad?"

Comment: @theGleep - I updated the question with more details. Please have a look when you get time.

Comment: We need more details on what the problem actually *is* ... can you run your program?  Can you put a breakpoint in your code?  Where does it fail?